# Preferences for opening curly brackets in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this problem.

Because i always put "{" in the same line of the function name, like:

```
- (void)doSomething {
   ...
}
```

it's annoying that Xcode creates functions like:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   ...
}
```

So, is there any option to change this behavior of Xcode?

Comment: There is an option to change that.  If you muck around in the settings you'll fine a settings page for the editor -- can't point you at it directly since I'm not on a Mac right now.

Comment: Couldn't find that option yet, would be cool if you can post the direct way, when you have time and a Mac :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go look in the Xcode app bundle (Ctrl-click on it and choose Show Package Contents) and then go to Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates and find the actual template files.

Then you can change the format of the default code to your hearts content. Remember that upgrading Xcode will probably undo your changes.

Additionally why not post a ticket on bug report.apple.com asking for more consistent template code :)